# TypeError: select_command() missing 1 required positional argument: 'mensaje'

Tags: mysql, python, python-3.x, base-de-datos

Hola tengo un error al llamar a la función que recibe de la base de datos, estoy haciendo un asistente virtual...

No sé por que no funciona ya que **self** no se llama en la funcion

**main.py**

```
from modules import database
import os

def arranque():
    os.system("clear")
    comando = input(">>> ")
    database.DataBase.select_command(comando)
    database.database.close()
arranque()
```

**database.py**

```
    def select_command(self, mensaje):
        consulta = mensaje
        sql = 'SELECT respuesta FROM respuestas WHERE pregunta={}'.format(mensaje)
        try:
            self.cursor.execute(sql)
            command = self.cursor.fetchone()
            print("Bot: " + command[2])
```

Answer (score 1):

### Por qué sucede este error

El problema es como has definido tu clase `DataBase` y el funcionamiento de las clases. Voy a empezar con un ejemplo desde el principio.

Cuando tu creas una clase, puedes introducir funciones dentro que son:

- Simples funciones: **una función** que **pertenece a la clase**
- Un método: **un método** que **pertenece a las instancias de la clase**

Vamos a ver esto creandonos una clase *tonta*:

```
class DataBase:
    def una_funcion():
        return "hola soy..."
    
    def un_metodo(self):
        return "hola soy: ", self


db = DataBase()
print("Llamamos a la función desde la clase: ", DataBase.una_funcion())
try:
    print("Llamamos a la función desde la instancia (no funciona): ", db.una_funcion())
except TypeError as e:
    print("TypeError: ", e)
try:
    print("Llamamos al método desde la clase (nos da tu error): ", DataBase.un_metodo())
except TypeError as e:
    print("TypeError: ", e)
print("Llamamos al métodos desde la instancia: ", db.un_metodo())
```

**Salida:**

```
Llamamos a la función desde la clase:  hola soy...
TypeError:  una_funcion() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
TypeError:  un_metodo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
Llamamos al métodos desde la instancia:  ('hola soy: ', <__main__.DataBase object at 0x7f91c4286990>)
```

Lo que está haciendo Python *por detrás* es:

- **Primer print**: lo que tenemos es `una función` que pertenece a una clase, la llamamos **desde la clase** y se ejecuta correctamente
- **Segundo print**: en este caso tenemos la misma función, pero NO la llamamos desde una clase, si no **desde un objeto que hemos instanciado**, Python cuando llama a los métodos de los objetos, inyecta un argumento (este argumento es el que ponemos por convención `self`) para referirse al propio objeto. En este caso, no hemos puesto `self` y la función tiene cero parámetros, Python llama a la función y le inyecta el parámetro `self` ¡ERROR! ya que `una_función` tiene 0 parámetros y Python no puede llamarla con un parámetro.
- **Tercer print** (este es tu caso): de nuevo llamamos a `un_método` **desde la clase**, cuando se llama a un método directamente desde la clase, **Python no necesita inyectar nada**, ya que está referenciado la propia clase, por lo que Python realiza el comportamiento del primer print, ¡ERROR! esto es un método perteneciente a una clase y tiene un parámetro `self` y al llamarlo directamente desde la clase Python no inyecta nada, por lo que tienes un método que requiere un parámetro y tu le estás pasando 0 parametros
- **Cuarto print**: Este es el caso más realizado, esta vez **llamamos al objeto que tenemos instanciado** y tienes un método por tanto tiene el argumento `self`. Como hemos dicho, Python inyecta el propio objeto como primer argumento y puede hacerlo satisfactoriamente, porque dicho método exige un parámetro para ser introducido.

De hecho en este último caso, vemos como al imprimir el self nos dice:

```
hola soy: ', <__main__.DataBase object at 0x7f91c4286990>)
```

Que quiere decir: **Hola soy un objeto de la clase DataBase**

### Solución

Como podemos ver en tu problema es que **estás llamando a un método**, pero los métodos solo pueden ser llamados desde objetos instanciados, NO desde la propia clase directamente.

Hay tres soluciones posibles a tu caso:

1. Quitar el `self` de `DataBase.select_command()` y así podrás ejecutar dicha función directamente desde la clase (NO recomendado).
2. Instanciar un objeto `DataBase` y desde ahí llamar al método `.select_command()`. Por ejemplo:

```
db = DataBase()
db.select_command()
```

3. Utilizar el decorador `@classmethod` (recomendado): este decorador hace que la función que no tiene self, sea un método pero en vez de tener que pertenecer a un objeto, **pertenece la propia clase**, por lo que python en la compilación, cuando se llame a dicha función inyectará siempre la propia clase `DataBase`, tanto si el método es llamado desde la clase o desde un objeto. Es decir **funcionan ambas formas**, vamos a demostrarlo

```
class DataBase:
    @classmethod
    def un_class_method(cls):
        return "hola soy...", cls

db = DataBase()
print("Llamamos al metodo de clase desde la clase: ", DataBase.un_class_method())
print("Llamamos al método de clase desde la instancia: ", db.un_class_method())
```

**Salida**

```
Llamamos al metodo de clase desde la clase:  ('hola soy...', <class '__main__.DataBase'>)
Llamamos al método de clase desde la instancia:  ('hola soy...', <class '__main__.DataBase'>)
```

Vemos como a pesar de haber sido llamado desde el objeto, no pone nada de que es un objeto, porque con `@classmethod` le hemos dicho que es un método perteneciente a la clase.

### En resumen

En tu método `select_command()` de tu clase `DataBase` utiliza el decorador `@classmethod` para poder llamar al método tanto de un objeto instanciado como de una clase. Quedaría así tu clase:

```
class DataBase:
    
    @classmethod
    def select_command(cls, comando):
        ...
```

### Extras

- El parámetro `self` es un simple argumento usado por convención, pero no significa nada para el interprete de Python, por lo que se podría usar cualquier palabra
- De la misma forma el parámetro `cls` es otra convención que no significa nada para el interprete de Python, se utiliza con los `classmethod`